# Input elements (checkbox) inside Recharts tick

Tags: reactjs, input, checkbox, bar-chart, recharts

I want to add checkbox under every bar in Recharts library. You can see needed result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yoJr.png). I think it should be implemented in custom tick `<XAxis dataKey="name" height={60} tick={<CustomizedAxisTick />} />`, but in example [here](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomizedLabelLineChart) I can see only SVG layout.

Is there way to implement feature like in the attached image? My current implementation (recharts version 2.7.2)

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BarChart,
  Bar,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  ReferenceLine,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  LabelList,
} from 'recharts';

const data = [
  {
    name: 'Ingredient 1',
    deviation: 9,
    data: {
      alertCount: 8,
      deviation: 9,
    },
    fill: '#007DC5',
  },
  {
    name: 'Ingredient 2',
    deviation: 144,
    data: {
      alertCount: 7,
      deviation: 144,
    },
    fill: '#007DC5',
  },
  {
    name: 'Ingredient 3',
    deviation: -10,
    data: {
      alertCount: 4,
      deviation: -10,
    },
    fill: '#E46A68',
  },
  {
    name: 'Ingredient 4',
    deviation: -212,
    data: {
      alertCount: 8,
      deviation: -212,
    },
    fill: '#E46A68',
  },
  {
    name: 'Ingredient 5',
    deviation: 25,
    data: {
      alertCount: 3,
      deviation: 25,
    },
    fill: '#007DC5',
  },
];
export const LoadDeviationWidgetL = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
        <BarChart
          width={500}
          height={300}
          data={data}
          margin={{
            top: 5,
            right: 30,
            left: 20,
            bottom: 5,
          }}
        >
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
          <XAxis dataKey="name" color="#46BC01" />
          <YAxis domain={[-50, 50]} allowDataOverflow />
          <Tooltip />
          <ReferenceLine y={0} stroke="#000" />
          <Bar dataKey="deviation">
            <LabelList dataKey="data" />
          </Bar>
        </BarChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by passing ref to the Bar:

```
const [barParams, setBarParams] = useState();

const getCoordinates = useCallback((node) => {
       if (node !== null) {
    const barParams = node.state.curData!.map(({ x, width, data: { 
           ingredientId } }) => ({x, id: ingredientId, width,}));

 setBarParams(barParams);
  }
},
[data],
 );
...
return <Bar dataKey="data.deviation" ref={getCoordinates} onClick={onClick}>
   <LabelList dataKey="data"/>
 </Bar>
...
```

And then when you have `bars` array you can use coordinates for checkbox positioning (x & width props), something like that:

```
export const AlertBarChartForm: React.FC<ChartFormProps> = ({ barParams, handleSubmit }) => (
  <form id="chart-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    {barParams.map(({ id, width, x }) => {
      return (
        <Field
          key={id}
          name={id}
          component="input"
          type="checkbox"
          style={{ position: 'absolute', left: x + width / 2 - 7 }}
        />
      );
    })}
  </form>
);
```